# How to get additional (intent) data from the second activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I use the following code to pass data between activities:

**ActivityOne.class**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
mIntent.putExtra("test", test_value);
startActivityForResult(mIntent, 0);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Result: "+resultCode); // OK
    final String test_value = data.getExtras().getString("test"); // fails here since data is null
    Log.i(TAG, "Test: "+test_value);

}
```

**ActivityTwo.class**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ...
    setResult(result); // pass the result back to ActivityOne
    finish(); // yes, I close it immediately after start ;)
```

So, how should I properly pass Intent data (`test_value` in the code above) from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo (this part works well) and then back to ActivityOne (this part doesn't work, `data` at `onActivityResult` is `null`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the Intent back.

Try:

```
 setResult(result, getIntent());
```

This will send the original intent that started Activity2 (i.e. created in Activity1) back to Activity1

Reference [Activity.getIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)